# Unity config working backwards

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have the following config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity1" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
    <section name="unity2" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <unity1 configSource="unity1.config" />
  <unity2 configSource="unity2.config" />
</configuration>
```

and the following in the unity1 file (unity2 is the same but with 2 instead of 1 in the obvious places.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<unity1 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <alias alias="IInjectMe1" type="CommonLib.IInjectMe1, CommonLib"/>
  <container name="unity1">
    <register type="IInjectMe1" name="Injected1" mapTo="CommonLib.InjectMe1, CommonLib" />
  </container>
</unity1>
```

I have this code in a single class file in an assembly called CommonLib:

```
        public void StartUp()
    {
        var config1 = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity1");
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        config1.Configure(container, "unity1");

        var config2 = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity2");
        config2.Configure(container, "unity2");

        var test1 = container.Resolve<InjectMe1>(); // WHY NOT THE INTERFACE??

        var test2 = container.Resolve<InjectMe2>(); // WHY NOT THE INTERFACE??

        Console.WriteLine(test1 != null && test2 != null);
    }
}

public class InjectMe1 : IInjectMe1 {}

public interface IInjectMe1 {}

public class InjectMe2 : IInjectMe2 {}

public interface IInjectMe2 {}
```

My question is, above where I've put "WHY NOT THE INTERFACE" why am I having to specify the concrete class instead of the interface? I'm sure it's just late and I can't see the wood for the trees, but I have to specify the concrete type and it creates the correct concrete type. I want to specify the interface and have it resolve.

I want `container.Resolve<IInjectMe1>()` to work. Note the I for interface.

Edit: If I do the above I get the error:

> Test method CommonLib.Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "CommonLib.IInjectMe1", name = "(none)".
>   Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>   Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, CommonLib.IInjectMe1, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Comment: You don't have to, you can specify interface. Do you get errors with `container.Resolve<IInjectMe1>()`?

Comment: Yes: var test1 = container.Resolve<IInjectMe1>(); gives me the error: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "CommonLib.IInjectMe1", name = "(none)".

Comment: Remove name="injected1" from your xml config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have the compiler at hand but I suspect you'd have to remove name="Injected1" from the XML.

By creating a named registration, you constrain yourself to named resolving. But apparently, you resolve a default registration.

Comment: That got it. I'm finding the documentation a bit fragmented, so pulling bits of examples from various sources. I'm not at all happy that adding a name fundamentally changes the way it operates like that. It doesn't seem logical.

Comment: It is really handy. Named registrations allow you to have conditional registrations, resolved by name.

Comment: Yeah, I'm slowly getting the way it's constructed. There's a lot of power, I'm hoping some of the interception stuff works well.

Comment: Just in case anyone has the same problem I had with the documenation, I've just found the proper codeplex page. http://unity.codeplex.com/releases